# Using im2rec in MXnet to create dataset with png images

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, docker, mxnet

I am trying to follow the example [here](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/tree/master/example/image-classification) and create my own dataset for training using MXnet.  My data is organized as specified in the example:

```
/data
    yes/
        file1.png
        file2.png
        ...
    no/
        file1.png
        file2.png
        ...
```

The tutorial says the first step is to run `im2rec.py` to create a .lst file, then run `im2rec.py` again (different options) to create the .rec file.  To create the .lst file I type:

```
> python tools/im2rec.py my_data /data --list True --recursive True --train-ratio .75 --exts .png
```

After doing this, two files are created (as expected), `my_data_train.lst` and `my_data_val.lst`.  The total number of lines in the two files is the same as the number of files in my `yes/` and `no/` directory combined.  Then, I attempt to run `im2rec` a second time to create the `.rec` file using:

```
> python tools/im2rec.py my_data /data --resize 227 --num-thread 16
```

This runs for a few seconds and then (silently) crashes.  In the process it creates 4 empty files: `my_data_train.idx`, `my_data_train.rec`, `my_data_val.idx`, and `my_data_val.rec`.

**Question:** What do I need to do differently to be able to create a proper `.rec` file containing my own .png images?

**Extra Details:**

I am working inside a docker container (mxnet/python:gpu) provided by dmlc on docker hub; they also provided the example on their github page.  The data is available through a shared directory in the container.  So it is presumably possible that this is a docker issue.  What makes me slightly worried that it is a docker issue is that I had to `pip install opencv-python` in order for `im2rec` to be able to import cv2... I would have hoped that the people providing the container would have taken care of this.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the image is missing opencv for python. Instead of installing via pip, please do `apt-get install python-opencv`.

PR posted here: [Using im2rec in MXnet to create dataset with png images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528997/using-im2rec-in-mxnet-to-create-dataset-with-png-images)